# How can I display my updated dice value in my dice game app?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I am developing a dice game application and I have recently restructured my app to split out the components so that each one has a specific function. At the moment I am working on the dice-roll component, using an @Output and an EventEmitter to pass my event (clicking a button to roll the dice) to my dice game component where I want it to display each value.

The event is working because when I do a console.log(newValue) in the 'update' function in my dice-game component, I get a number in the console between 1 and 6. However I cannot seem to get this value to display in the browser.

Ideally the value would be passed to my dice-roll.component.html file where I can display it between the span tags. The value would then be visible in the browser because I have already added the  tags into the dice-game.component.html.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**dice-game.component.html:**

```html
<div>
    <app-dice-roll *ngFor="let diceValue of diceValues; let i = index" (onRoll)="update(i, $event)"></app-dice-roll>
</div>
```

**dice-game.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dice-game',
    templateUrl: 'dice-game.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dice-game.component.css']
})

export class DiceGameComponent {
    diceValues: Array<number> = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    update(i, newValue) {
        this.diceValues[i] = newValue;
        console.log(newValue);
    }
}
```

**dice-roll.component.html:**

```html
<div class="dice-roll">
    <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
</div>
<button type="button" id="roll-button" (click)="diceRoller()">Roll!</button>
```

**dice-roll.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dice-roll',
    templateUrl: 'dice-roll.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dice-roll.component.css']
})
export class DiceRollComponent {
    @Output()
    onRoll: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
    diceRoller() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.onRoll.emit(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        }, 750);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your new diceValue in the dice-roll component (your child component), you need to pass this value to the dice-roll component by creating an @Input() property in this dice-roll component.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dice-roll',
    templateUrl: 'dice-roll.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dice-roll.component.css']
})
export class DiceRollComponent {
    @Input() diceValue: number;
    @Output() onRoll: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();  
    ...
}
```

You can then pass your value from the dice-game component (Parent component) to the dice-roll component (Child component) by the following code:

in HTML:

```html
<div>
    <app-dice-roll *ngFor="let diceValue of diceValues; let i = index" 
      [diceValue]="diceValue" (onRoll)="update(i, $event)"></app-dice-roll>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in .ts =>**

```
diceValue:int = 0

rollDice() {
 this.diceValue = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1)
}
```

**in .html =>**

```
 <button (click)="rollDice()"> Roll that dice! </button>
 <h2>dice value is: {{diceValue}}</h2>
```